# How to make the cursor behave like a text editor/terminal in curses/C?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

For example, say I have the string "Hinge" - I want to be able to move the cursor to the beginning, hit del to remove the "H", and insert a "B", pushing everything in front of the cursor forward and creating the word "Binge", instead of overwriting the "i" which is the default behaviour. Can I do this using the standard addch() function?

Also, even if I could get it to print properly on the screen, it seems like an overly complex problem getting this to correspond to a buffer. This seems like it would be a common task but I can't think of a non-hacky way to do it.

Here's an example of how I'm currently dealing with basic input.

```
  if (isprint(key)) {
    if (ctx->pos != sizeof(ctx->line)-1) {
      mvwaddch(self->window, y, x, key);
      ctx->line[ctx->pos++] = key;
      ctx->line[ctx->pos] = '\0';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm since it's C, not sure if this is the best method, but have you thought of coding class with a linked list of chars and functions to write in it? You could also set flags such as the "Insert" button to overwrite or just add another character and push everything forward.

Comment: Consider using the [GNU readline library](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GNU readline library](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline) to accomplish this instead of coding directly to curses. Here is a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main () {
    char *s = readline("Type something: ");
    printf("You typed: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, I compiled with `gcc prog.c -lreadline -ltermcap`

Comment: @JohnF: You are very welcome. Remember that the string returned by `readline()` needs to be freed with `free()`.

Comment: On further investigation it looks like curses and readline are incompatible.